# How to initalize a vector inherited from base class in derived constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, initialization, access-control

I know that i can iniatlize the vector of the base class in the derived like this:

#### Base.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

public:
  Base(std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > vec);
  ~Base();
private:
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > vec_;
```

#### Base.cpp

```
Base::Base(std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > vec) : vec_(vec)
{
}
```

#### Derived.cpp

```
Dervied::Derived : Base({{0, 0}, {1, 1}})
{
}
```

But is there also a way to initalize the vector vec_ of this base class in the child?

#### Base.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

public:
  Base();
  ~Base();
private:
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > vec_;
```

#### Base.cpp

```
Base::Base()
{
}
```

So something like:

```
Derived::Derived : Base(vec_({{0, 0}, {1, 1}}))
```

Or is this not possible at all in C++?

Comment: As an aside: 1. Blindly putting every class into its own file is a overly broad mis-application of modularisation guidelines. 2. A [mcve] should consist of as many files as needed to demonstrate the point, and no more.

Comment: What do you expect `Derived::Derived() : Base(vec_({{0, 0}, {1, 1}})) {}` - if it was valid, which it isn't - to achieve that `Derived::Derived() : Base({{0, 0}, {1, 1}}) {}` does not achieve?    Your aim seems to be to initialise the `vec_` member of `Base`  - but the base class constructor does that.   Bear in mind that constructing the base class initialises all members of the base class that have appropriate constructors - so selecting the right constructor is the way to initialise the members as needed.

Comment: I just want to initalize the vector with different values in each derived class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vec_` is `private`. Hence, it is not accessible in the derived class. You could make it `protected` if you need to access it in the derived class.

As your classes stand at the moment, you can only modify `vec_` through the base class constructor.

If there were some other base class methods accessible to the derived class that modified `vec_` then you could use them to change `vec_`.

Comment: Thank you, so the only way is to either make it protected or to use the base class' constructor like  Base(std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > vec); and then initalize it like this in derived: Dervied::Derived : Base({{0, 0}, {1, 1}}) ?